# Cannot launch Jupyter notebooks in Apache Spark Starter in Bluemix

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I unbinded Apache Spark Starter from its Object Storage service and then binded back. After that I cannot launch Jupyter notebooks. Is it something to be expected and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The Spark Starter does not expect the obj storage service to change after initial binding, so I would not expect this to work. Best is to create a new Spark Starter app if at all possible.